# Interface builder says that UITableView cells need constraints, but they don't

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode9

I have a view controller with a `UITableView`. I set it to have dynamic prototype cells, set the first cell's style "Custom", add some subviews to the cell.

Whenever I do something like this, IB complains, shows red warnings, and refuses to layout the cell, even though it works fine in the running app. What is the problem?

Screenshots below show the details.

First, a `UITextField` is floating half above the cell, despite having a center-y constraint to it's superview, which should place it in the middle of the cell.

[image]
[image]

Clicking the "Update frames" button does nothing.

IB also makes false claims about the image view on the left. It says it needs a "Y position or height". But, it has both: a 50 pt height, and  constraints to the top and bottom of the cell.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest starting fresh... delete the elements from your cell... set your cell height to `70`... add an image view, and size it to `50 x 50` and position it `10` from the top and `10` from the left.. set it's constraints to `Top: 10 / Leading: 10 / Bottom: 10 / Width: 50 / Height: 50` and see if IB tells you it's OK or not. Then add your text field, set its Leading constraint (of `20` from the image view`) and Centered Vertically. See if IB is OK. Then add the "eye" image (or button) and set its constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Your thumb image constraints are likely in conflict with each other for the height of the prototype cell. The top space + bottom space + height are greater than the prototype cell height. Interface Builder doesn't know how to lay this out or which constraint to break. You have a few options:

1. Modify the height of the prototype cell to match the expected height so the constraints don't conflict.
2. Change one of the 3 constraints to less than required priority. This will allow Interface Builder to break that constraint to satisfy the other two.
3. Change the constraints to fit the prototype cell height. Similar to option 1, but changing the constraints to fit the height rather than changing the height to fit the constraints.

Interface Builder isn't very forgiving when it comes to cell heights, especially when they include a content view that has a fractional height due to the separator. I'm guessing your issue is from the total of those 3 constraints equalling 70, but your content view height being something like 70.5. I've found it's usually better to use a top constraint, height constraint, and vertically center in container constraint instead of top, height, and bottom.

Comment: In the app, I'm using autolayout to calculate the table row heights. That's odd that they don't have an equivalent in IB, to set the cell height from it's internal views. I'm trying option #1, and it's worked to get rid of the red errors, but "update frames" button still doesn't layout the cell.

Comment: @RobN If you have valid constraints, you can use automatic dimensions in storyboard, or return UITableViewAutomaticDimension programatically. Sometimes you will need to adjust the Vertical Compression Resistance and Content Hugging Priority of one view to allow it to be flexible.

Comment: @JakeG I'm setting the rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension in code, but where is the equivalent option in the IB storyboard? I don't see it.

Comment: I believe code always overrides Storyboard anyways, so if the constraints are valid that 'should' work. But, in storyboard if you click on your tableview, under Size Inspector (the ruler icon), make sure Row Height is checked for automatic.